# dash:plotly w/ "backend" that has a 100 subscriber threads

Tags: plotly-dash

Dash has been an amazing tool for out company to quickly convert plotly charts to simple web applications.  Recently we started taking these charts into the live data domain and are starting to run into some scalability issues.   (One main goal we have is to keep the complexity of this system as simple as possible.  Although that may be at odds with some of our scalability.)

The requirements of the charts is a low speed refresh.  Every ~10 seconds is fine.

As we scaled the application from 1 -> say 64 subscriber/managers things have worked great.  Now we are getting into the domain of > 100 threads and things are starting to degrade.

I'm looking for some guidance.  Is it time to start dividing this application?  Split the subscriber/managers into there own app (and or apps) and just stuff the data into redis/etc.  Then dash can grab it from there.

Do you think its still possible to maintain the single application model?  Feels like we might be fighting against pythons GIL?

On the "backend" we are creating ZMQ subscribers that run on their own python "thread".  The volume of the data ranges where most messages are fairly small < 100 bytes.  Although on a couple subscribers we do receive larger messages > 1k.  I would say the rate of messages is fairly "average", nothing extreme.

Next we leverage "controllers" that are registered for a callback, update() from the subscriber.  These update() functions run on the subscriber thread.  We keep the managers use of the update() thread as light as possible.  Just place the data if the manager wants it into "its" memory.  These managers then have there own python "thread" where they wake on an interval and do some processing of the data.  The simplest processing example is one manager manages a sliding window of N seconds and calculates the average bandwidth received for a subscriber over that period with a refresh rate of maybe 1-2 seconds.  The managers attempt to place the result in a memory buffer where a final answer rests.

Then the dash callback then grabs 1-N managers date and formats it into a chart.

Python locking is used across each of the data boundaries.

(Some of the controllers didn't follow our golden run.  Light use of the subscribers thread.  And data must be processed before the dash callback picks it up, to avoid more processing on the dash callback leading to timeouts.  Those need reworked.  Dropping those cases we are still seeing some startup timeouts as all the threads get going.)

We switched to gunicorn for a more "production" server.  As part of this we increased the number of --threads some and increased the --timeout.  Those have allowed the application to continue working for most part.